# The given key was not present in the dictionary - Error: _HResult -2146232969

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving the error "The given key was not present in the dictionary" while running the below, any ideas how to fix this ? Thank you

```
            Dim con As New SqlConnection
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            Try
                Dim InsertCommand As New SqlCommand

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowdata.Item(0)", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(0)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowdata.Item(1)", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(1)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowdata.Item(2)", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(2)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowdata.Item(3)", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(3)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowdata.Item(4)", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(4)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowdata.Item(5)", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(5)

            Catch ex1 As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error!" & ex1.Message)

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO allData (Name, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5, Num6) VALUES (@Name,rowData.Item(0),rowData.Item(1),rowData.Item(2),rowData.Item(3),rowData.Item(4),rowData.Item(5))"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Finally
                con.Close()
            End Try
```

Comment: -1 for no research effort.

Comment: Of course I did a wide research and spent a long time on it ! But since you're the "expert", if you can find the right data online, paste it here !

Comment: Perhaps I phrased myself incorrectly. No research effort does not mean you did not do any research. It means your question does not show any. Part of it, you did not provide a reduced test case, i.e. a way to reproduce your issue without having your database. Also the term "research" does not mean "googling". Right now the question stands as "I have this error, here is my code", even without a line number on which the error happened. You will get more answers faster if you account for the issues I outlined. You will also learn better by doing that, and soon end up being an expert yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to

```
Try
    Dim InsertCommand As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@num1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(0)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@num2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(1)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@num3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(2)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@num4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(3)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@num5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(4)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@num6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rowData.Item(5)
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO allData (Name, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5, Num6) " + 
                      "VALUES (@Name,@num1,@num2,@num3,@num4,@num5,@num6)"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex1 As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error!" & ex1.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

As you have written the code above, the execution of the command is inside the catch clause and this means that it is executed only if there is an exception in the preparation of the Parameters.
However this could only be a typo, more problematic are the parameter names.
I suggest you to simplify the placeholders names using a simple pattern.

Comment: Awesome ! It worked, i got the data in the table as I needed ! thanks a lot Steve, u're a genius !